# How to count "times per second" in a correct way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Goal: I would like to see how many times python is able to print something per 1 second.

For educational purposes I'm trying to make a script that shows how many times per every second a random module will appear in a loop. How to do it in a fastest pythonic way?

At first, to count seconds I wrote this code:

```
import time

sec = 0

while True:
    print(sec)
    time.sleep(1)
    sec += 1
```

But this one seems slower than a real seconds.

So I decided to use local seconds. Also, before continue my script I wanted to count how many times python will print 'you fool' manually, so I wrote following code:

```
import time   

def LocalSeconds():
    local_seconds = time.gmtime()[5:-3]
    local_seconds = int(local_seconds[0])
    return local_seconds


while True:
    print(LocalSeconds(), 'you fool')
```

Output: 
first second - 14 times per second;
next second - 13 times;
next second - 12 times, etc. Why it goes slower?

Where I end / stuck right now:

```
import time, random


def RandomNumbers():
    return random.randint(3,100)


def LocalSeconds():
    local_seconds = time.gmtime()[5:-3]
    local_seconds = int(local_seconds[0])
    return local_seconds


def LocalSecondsWithPing():
    local_seconds_ping = time.gmtime()[5:-3]
    local_seconds_ping = int(local_seconds[0:1])
    return local_seconds_ping



record_seconds = []
record_seconds_with_ping = []



while True:
    record_seconds.append(LocalSeconds())
    record_seconds_with_ping.append(LocalSecondsWithPing())

    if record_seconds == record_seconds_with_ping:
        RandomNumbers()
        del record_seconds_with_ping[0]

    del record_seconds[-1]
```

Also, I guess I need to use "for" loop, not "while"? How to do this script?

Comment: You should use the `timeit` module.

Comment: Something must be very strange here... On a low-powered VPS of mine your example with `gmtime` prints well over 100000 times per second. What do you suppose is making your script so slow?

Answer (score 0):

Counting a single second won't give you a good result. The number of prints in a single second may vary depending on things like other threads currently running on your system (for the OS or other programs) and may be influenced by other unknown factor.

Consider the followind code:

```
import calendar
import time


NumOfSeconds=100                              #Number of seconds we average over
msg='Display this message'                    #Message to be displayed
count=0                                       #Number of time message will end up being displayed
#Time since the epoch in seconds + time of seconds in which we count
EndTime=calendar.timegm(time.gmtime()) + NumOfSeconds  

while calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())<EndTime: #While we are not at the end point yet
    print(msg)                                #Print message
    count=count+1                             #Count message printed

print(float(count)/NumOfSeconds)              #Average number of prints per second
```

Here calendar.timegm(time.gmtime()) gives us the time in seconds since the epoch (if you don't know what that is, read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). But basically it's just a fixed point in time most computer system now days use as a reference point.
So we set the EndTime to that point + the number of seconds we want to average over. Then, in a loop, we print the message we want to test and count the number of times we do that, between every iteration checking that we are not past the end time. 
Finally we print the average number of times per seconds that we printed the message. This helps with the fact that we may end up start counting near the end of a whole second since the epoch, in which case we won't actually have a whole second to print messages, but just a fraction of that. If we make sure NumOfSeconds is large enough, that error addition will be small (for example, for NumOfSeconds=100 that error is ~1%).

We should note that the actual number would also depend on the fact that we are constantly testing the current time and counting the number of prints, however, while I haven't tested that here, it is usually the case that printing to the screen takes significantly longer time than those operations.